# Features backward elimination statsmodels OLS when considering interactions

Tags: regression, p-value, feature-selection, statsmodels

I have a multi linear regression problem,

$Y$ is my target and $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are my features.

In my regression, I consider the interaction between $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and I add a bias.

So my problem is given by :
$Y  \sim X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_1X_2 + X_1X_3+ X_2X_3+ bias$

Now, I fit my model with `statsmodels.api.sm` and I want to eliminate the feature the highest p value recursively.

- My first question is : for example, if the highest p value is for the $X_1X_2$ feature, is it okay to eliminate this feature even when $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be statistically significant ?
- My second question : in the case when all the interaction of some feature have a p value greater than 0.05 in the first iteration, Could I eliminate this feature and all the interactions ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you clarify the second question? Are you saying that, for example, all the interactions with $X_3$ are greater than 0.05, and you're wondering if you can remove $X_3$ *and* all interactions with $X_3$?

Comment: I am saying that the p values of $X_3$ and all the interactions with $X_3$ are greater than 0.05. Could I remove $X_3$ and all interactions with it in one iteration, because normally we eliminate one feature each time